# CSS: centering block elements

Tags: css

So I have a bunch of elements that need to have a specific width, height and padding and need to be centered within their parent element:

```
<div class="pages">
    <a>Page 1</a>
    <a>Page 2</a>
    <a>Page 3</a>
</div>
```

How do I do this? I don't know how many elements there will be so .pages can't have a defined width so margin:auto; won't work.

Comment: Horizontally, Vertically, or both?

Answer (score 2):

In the stylesheet or style tag:

```
margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto
```

Comment: This will not work probably. What element are you suggesting to set this style to?

Comment: The inner block, ie. the one you are setting the height and width for.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap all those in one single div and center this one, this will be the usual approach I believe.

```
<div id="wrapper" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
  <div id="page1"> ... </div>
  <div id="page1"> ... </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: This only works when #wrapper has a defined width and I don't know how wide it should be because I don't know how many elements it'll contain and in order for this to work wrapper has to be equal to combined widths of all the elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you have working code, please post it.

It sounds like what you're looking for is `margin: auto` on the elements you want to center, like so:

```
#my_div {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: I tried to post it but the stupid editor sees it like HTML instead of code despite having four spaces in front.

Comment: Also this doesn't work when #my_div doesn't have a defined width and since I don't know how many elements it'll contain I don't know how wide it should be.

Comment: Ah, well, you said "specific width" in your question. That changes it.

Comment: In that case, you could specify the width with inline styles when you are building the page, or with javascript afterwards.

Comment: @A-OK: you can format code with the code button in the editor.  Just highlight the code and click the curly braces button, that should do the trick.

Comment: The child elements need to have width, height and padding, the container element can't have a defined width because I don't know how many child elements it'll have.

Comment: yeah, good idea... I'll just see how many elements it has and each time put a specific width in an inline style. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CSS CODE

```
div {
 display:table-cell;
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 vertical-align:middle;
 background: red;
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<div>
    Hello...This is Vertically Centered!
</div>
<div>
    Hello...2!
</div>
<div>
    Hello...3!
</div>
```

SAMPLE DISPLAY

[image: Sample Display]

Comment: As an example...this creates a red box and places the 3 strings side by side centered in the middle (lining up horizontally).